# Rails: what happens to data after migrating column from decimal to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I could always risk botching my dev database (PostgreSQL) & rebuild it but thought I'd ask first to see if someone had experience.

Ideally all data would be truncated to its integer amount: (eg: 5.7 would become 5) or perhaps it would round values (5.7 becomes 6)? or perhaps it simply nullifies or zeros out all values and data is lost? I suppose the worst outcome would be unreliable data (5.7 becomes 23).

Is there a general rule of thumb for these types of migrations?

```
class ChangeBookFromDecimalToInteger < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   change_column :book, :price, :integer
  end

  def self.down
   change_column :book, :price, :decimal
  end
end
```

Comment: An incidental point here is that you're lucky enough to be using a database where EVERYTHING except create / drop database and create / drop tablespace and sequences and their functions are transactable. So try what you're looking at doing in a transaction on your dev database and see what happens.  If you're not 100% happy, just roll it back. Note now is a good time to learn how to drive your db from the psql command interface, which is quite powerful and user friendly.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you... Are you saying that it might be more advantageous to run migrations, like this, from the `psql` command line as opposed to a Rails migration? I would think this would be dangerous because other users on team wouldn't have easy access in repository to same migration. Or maybe you were just saying use command line to 'play' around with migrations until you find what you need because they're easy to roll back?!?

Comment: You could do either or both really.  But definitely to test what happens etc.  For instance as mentioned elsewhere active record doesn't understand the using clause, so if you need one you'll be migrating your data by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ActiveRecord will send an ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ... TYPE to the database and the database will perform the type conversion. PostgreSQL will convert `decimal` to `int` using `round`:

```
=> create table with_decimal (n decimal(11, 6));
=> insert into with_decimal (n) values (1.0),(1.1),(1.5),(1.6),(1.9);
=> insert into with_decimal (n) values (-1.0),(-1.1),(-1.5),(-1.6),(-1.9);
=> select * from with_decimal;
     n     
-----------
  1.000000
  1.100000
  1.500000
  1.600000
  1.900000
 -1.000000
 -1.100000
 -1.500000
 -1.600000
 -1.900000
(10 rows)

=> alter table with_decimal alter column n type int;
=> select * from with_decimal;
 n  
----
  1
  1
  2
  2
  2
 -1
 -1
 -2
 -2
 -2
(10 rows)
```

Note that [`round(numeric)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) rounds to the nearest integer.

If you want specific conversion behavior, you should say so with a USING in the [ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html):

> The optional `USING` clause specifies how to compute the new column value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as an assignment cast from old data type to new. A `USING` clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

If you need a USING clause, you have to issue the ALTER TABLE by hand as ActiveRecord doesn't know anything about USING, for example:

```
def up
    connection.execute(%q{
        alter table books
        alter column price 
        type integer
        using trunc(price * 100)
    })
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consult PostreSQL manual on how it handles queries like "ALTER TABLE ... CHANGE COLUMN ... " and how it converts data between corresponding types.
All DB Schema change migrations in Rails are handled by corresponding database backend.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is that if you are going to have to migrate, and you need explicit requirements, create the new column, use Ruby to convert the columns, then delete the old column. If you don't care about the data, let the DB do it via `ALTER TABLE`